# WeakValueDictionary in python

Tags: python

What is WeakValueDictionary from weakref ? I know it allows to store items in dictionary without garbage collector caring about them but when should they be used? I don't know the example of the situation where we would want to bypass garbage collector in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a reference from the official python manual:

`A weak reference to an object is not enough to keep the object alive: when the only remaining references to a referent are weak references, garbage collection is free to destroy the referent and reuse its memory for something else. A primary use for weak references is to implement caches or mappings holding large objects, where it’s desired that a large object not be kept alive solely because it appears in a cache or mapping.`

Answer (score 2):

As can be found in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/weakref.html), use Weak references if you need to index a large object for some reason, but don't want to keep it around if something else deletes it. Perhaps I am storing cryptographic classes, which contain quite a bit of internal stuff, in a dictionary. If one of the classes is deleted, then I can save memory.